# WinForms form localization fails for a control property with both Localizable and DefaultValue attributes set if the property is not top-level

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, internationalization, default-value

I have a custom WinForms control in which there are several text properties. They are sub-properties of an object property. They are defined like this:

```c#
[DefaultValue("Default caption text")]
[Localizable(true)]
public string Caption
{
    // get {}
    // set {}
}
```

As you can see, both [Localizable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute) and [DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute) attributes are set for them. It turned out that the standard WinForms designer localization technique does not work correctly for these properties. If the form's `Localizable` property is set to True and I change the form's Language property, non-default values for these properties are copied to another language or even the default form language, and the like.

I tired to remove the `DefaultValue` attribute and mimic its functionality with the equivalent ShoulSerialize*PropertyName* and Reset*PropertyName* methods, but this did not help.

As I could conclude, the problem is related to non-empty default values of properties. The only workaround could be setting the variables behind these properties to their default values in the control constructor, but in this case the property values look bold (changed) in the property grid and their non-default values are duplicated in the form's .designer.cs file. But it's a bad effect: me and other developers do not expect this because the properties have not been changed explicitly by a human.

Are there any solutions or workarounds to this problem?

---

IMPORTANT. The problem occurs if my specific properties are sub-properties of an object property that has an attached custom type converter for expandable objects. A simplified look of this construction is the following:

```c#
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private SettingsProperty settings = new SettingsProperty();

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class SettingsProperty
    {
        private const string CaptionDefaultValue = "Caption default value";
        private string caption = CaptionDefaultValue;

        [DefaultValue(CaptionDefaultValue)]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Caption
        {
            get { return caption; }
            set { if (caption != value) caption = value; }
        }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyExpandableTypeConverter))]
    public SettingsProperty Settings
    {
        get { return settings; }
    }
}

internal class MyExpandableTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
     // Class implementation - about 500 lines
}
```

The problem does not occur if my specific properties are top-level properties of the control like this:

```c#
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const string CaptionDefaultValue = "Caption default value";
    private string caption = CaptionDefaultValue;

    [DefaultValue(CaptionDefaultValue)]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return caption; }
        set { if (caption != value) caption = value; }
    }
}
```

If I replace `MyExpandableObjectConverter` with .NET's intrinsic [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter) class, the problem does not disappear. This causes me to think that the problem is not in `MyExpandableObjectConverter` class. It seems it is somewhere in .NET in the WinForms designer code that works with object properties.

Comment: I tried .NET 6 and .NET 4.8 and it works as expected. Here is the property:  `private const string CaptionDefaultValue = "Caption default value";
    private string caption = CaptionDefaultValue;
    [DefaultValue(CaptionDefaultValue)]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return caption; }
        set
        {
            if (caption != value)
                caption = value;
        }
    }`

Comment: @RezaAghaei, Is it a UserControl? Is it a top-level property in it? In my case the Caption property is a sub-property of a complex object property of a descendant of the [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class.

Comment: In my example it's a Control/UserControl and it's a top-level property. Then you need to post a [MCVE] to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I investigated the issue more. Indeed, the problem does not occur if properties are top-level properties of a control. The problem occurs if they are sub-properties of an object property. I updated the question with the corresponding details.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, the Microsoft example for [NotifyParentPropertyAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.notifyparentpropertyattribute) also can be used to reproduce the problem. Add `[Localizable(true)]` to the numeric `BorderSize` property. Drop the control on the form. `BorderSize` will be set to the default value of 1. Then set the form's Localizable property to True and switch to another language. Set `BorderSize` to 2. Then switch back to the default language. You will see that `BorderSize` is still set to 2 - though it must be 1!

Comment: I reproduced the problem and I can confirm the issue.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, Should we classify it as a bug then? And report the problem to Microsoft?

Comment: It's of course an unexpected behavior and it's a good idea to report it to Microsoft.